# When is the conjugate of a polynomial root also a root of the same polynomial?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers

1. Let $Z_0$ be a solution of $Z^{13}-13Z^{7}+7Z^{3}-3Z+1=0$, Is it true that $Z_0$'s conjugate is also a solution?
2. Let $Z_0$ be a solution of $Z^{2}+iZ+2=0$, Is it true that $Z_0$'s conjugate is also a solution?

Comment: I see that $i$ is one solution of the equation in 2)...

Comment: **Hint:** $z^2 + i z + 2 = (z+2i)(z-i)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally, if $f\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ is a polynomial and $f(a)=0$ for some $a\in\mathbb{C}$, then it is true that $f(\bar a)=0$ as well. You have to use that complex conjugation is an $\mathbb{R}$-linear operation (which is easy to check, really). Then,
$$ f(\bar a) = \sum_{i=0}^n b_i \overline{a}^i = \overline{\sum_{i=0}^n b_i a^i} = \overline{f(a)}= 0.$$

Comment: but, is it the same for the second one where one of the numbers is $i$?

Comment: @Some1, why did you accept a solution which, according to your own comment, does not fully answer your question(s)?

Comment: @Some1: The point to my statement is that $f$ has _real_ coefficients, but the second polynomial does not satisfy this condition. See I.J.Kennedy's answer.

Answer (score 2):

The main (first) question has been answered.  We deal with the second. Let $z_0$ be a solution of the equation $z^2+iz+2=0$.  Then $\overline{z_0}$ is a solution of the equation $z^2-iz+2=0$.  This equation is *different* from the equation $z^2+iz+2=0$.  So certainly we cannot conclude that $\overline{z_0}$ is a solution of the equation $z^2+iz+2=0$.

But this does not show that $\overline{z_0}$ is **not** a solution of the equation $z^2+iz+2=0$.

In fact, it isn't.  There are various ways to see this. We use an idea which is more general than necessary.

Note that the sum of the two roots of $z^2+iz+2$ is the negative of the coefficient of $z$.  So the sum of the roots is $-i$.  But $z_0+\overline{z_0}$ is real, so if $z_0$ is one root, $\overline{z_0}$ cannot be the other one.

Comment: That, or the fact that if $z$ solves $z^2+iz+2=0$ and $z^2-iz+2=0$, then $2iz=0$. Since $z=0$ does not solve $z^2+iz+2=0$, this is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

The two solutions of your second equation are $i$ and $-2i$, and these are not conjugates.